# How does the if($i ??? function look for a carousel displaying AABB

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a carousel with 4 items, they should appear in this order: AABB.
which means "active item mission" should be shown 2 times, same as "item mission". 
My question is how does the `if($i ???` function look in this case, as `if($i == 1)` is obviously not correct. 
Thank you!

```html
       <section id="mission" class="mission"><h1>Our Mission</h1>
        <div class="target" >
            <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade" id="carousel3" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">  

            <?php
            $i=1;
            $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
            ‘category_name’ => ‘Cars’,
            ‘posts_per_page’ => 4,
            'tag' => 'mission'
            ));
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_query->the_post();if($i == 1){  ?>
            <div class="active item mission">
            <h2 class="b"><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <h4 class="b"><?php the_content();?></h4>

            </div>
            <?php }
            else { ?>
            <div class="item mission">
            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <h4><?php the_content();?></h4>
            </div>
            <?php } $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
            </div>




            </div>     
            </div> 

            <a class="left carousel-control" href="mission #carousel3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span>
            </a>            
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="mission #carousel3" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span>
            </a>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="mission #carousel3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="mission #carousel3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="mission #carousel3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

        </section><!--#mission -->
```

Comment: you should reduce the width of active items to 50%

Comment: Sorry, it's not what i mean. They shouldn't be displayed in the same frame. It is about the order of appearance.

Comment: if you want in order you can sort by query ($the_query)

Comment: like order by....

Comment: is it not working with $i somehow to play twice "active item", and twice "item"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$i` is just a value that will be increment of 1 on the while loop.

The $i var is initialize with

```
$i = 1;
```

In the loop, the first element to pass, $i will have $i = 1, meaning that it's this first element. At the end of the loop iteration, `$i++;` is used to add 1 to $i.

For the second element `$i = 2`.

In your code, $i is just use to detect the first element of the results and apply a different structure.  In any case this value could be print two times.
You need to find another conditions

You can do it with a condition that will detect if $i is odd or even,

```
if($i % 2 == 0)
```

Hope it helps